# background sound during call in android

Tags: android

I want to play a sound automatically when I call to somebody
but I don't know the way for this.

It is possible because we have some application that play some noise (traffic and ...) to background of call but I could not find a code or something for this
[example of sound play in background](http://www.appbrain.com/app/fake-background-sounds/air.com.littleboydesign.background)

this is a code to play music

```
MediaPlayer player;
AssetFileDescriptor afd;
try {
    // Read the music file from the asset folder
    afd = getAssets().openFd(“home.mp3″);
    // Creation of new media player;
    player = new MediaPlayer();
    // Set the player music source.
    player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
    // Set the looping and play the music.
    player.setLooping(true);
    player.prepare();
    player.start();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

but can we use this during call?

Comment: What do you mean by "background music"? Do you want to hear the other person to hear the music? That's not supported.

Comment: its mean i dial a number in my app and a recorded music play when another person answered call

Comment: Yeah, but where do you want the music to be heard? On the device that's doing the playback, on the device of the person you're calling, or both?

Comment: i want to person that i called hear, and not important that on my device it heared or not

Comment: As I said in my first comment, that's not supported. Android apps aren't allowed to inject audio into the voice call uplink.

Comment: thank you but so how fake apps works? i think there must be a way to do this

Comment: I've no idea what that app claims to be able to do, or on which devices it works, so I can't really say how it does what it does.